# How to overwrite styles in Basscss with :root

Tags: css

I'm just setting up my first static site using [Basscss](http://www.basscss.com). As recommended, I don't want to overwrite styles with my own classes or id, but rather [change the default ones using the :root element](http://www.basscss.com/docs/btn-primary):

> Adjust the default colors using the --button-color and
>   --button-background-color custom properties.

But when I now add something like

```
:root {
  --button-color: red;
  --button-background-color: black;
}
```

to my own external stylesheet or even the header of the index.html, basically nothing happens. Am I missing something here in order to change element colors using :root?

Thanks already in advance!

Cheers,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

herbigt, sounds like you're missing a processor (like [cssnext](http://cssnext.io/) or [postcss](https://github.com/postcss/postcss)) that Basscss assumes in order to handle custom variables. Both of these processors are npm modules, and you can fit them into your development process by configuring your project's `package.json` file accordingly.

**I recommend you checkout [Bassplate](http://www.basscss.com/docs/guides/custom-builds/) to understand how to customize Basscss.**

Bassplate is the official boilerplate for customizing Basscss. The main resource it provides, in addition to the Basscss library, is a `package.json` config file that sets up your Basscss development environment, including build tools and build commands.

*The build tools*

1. `http-server` (serves your project to `localhost:8080` so you can see your work in a browser),
2. `watch` (which watches for file changes and rebuilds your css when changes are made), and
3. `cssnext` (which processes the `@imports` and other CSS4-like stuff inside the Basscss files.

The above three tools are listed in [the `devDependencies` section](https://github.com/basscss/bassplate/blob/v4.0.0/package.json#L57) of Bassplate's `package.json`.

*The build commands*

Bassplate's `package.json` file provides command scripts that tell the above 3 tools what to do. You can find these commands under [the `scripts` section](https://github.com/basscss/bassplate/blob/v4.0.0/package.json#L62) of the `package.json` file.

---

Basscss is looking ahead to the coming CSS4 specs that will hopefully include custom variables and more, ie:

```
:root {
  --button-color: red;
}
```

While CSS4 is not yet a standard, tools like postcss and cssnext allow us to implement CSS4 syntax. You can read about this in the Basscss docs section [Future CSS Syntax](http://www.basscss.com/docs/guides/future-css/).

Comment: The Bassplate link above resolves to a 404 page, found the git repo here https://github.com/basscss/bassplate